# How to programmatically identify and list fields with unique=True in any given model

Tags: django-models

My friends,

How would I do to identify, in any given model, which fields have the parameter unique=True? And how about unique_together. Is there a way to programmatically identify fields with this characteristics?

Answer (score 0):

Any instance from any model have a method called `_get_unique_checks()` that will return a list of tuples with all the fields that are marked as unique.

Similarly, any instance of any model have another method called `_check_unique_together()`.